# Couchbase N1QL: issue on querying array field

Tags: sql++

Hi I have a test doc like this:

```
{
  "doctype": "test",
  "users": [
    1,
    2
  ]
}
```

Then I used below query to get the result:

```
SELECT * FROM bucket WHERE doctype = "test" AND ANY user IN users SATISFIES user = 1 END;
```

But I got this error: "msg": "syntax error - at user".
Who knows where I got wrong? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`USER` is a reserved word.

You can use `u` instead, or place `USER` in back ticks to escape it.